# How do I prevent checking of duplicate elements in a array?

Tags: arrays, c, duplicates, nested-loops, frequency

I am checking frequency of each element in an array. The problem is the duplicate elements are counting themselves more than needed, I want to skip the counting procedure of the element which has been already counted.

```
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        bird = all[x];
        for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            if (all[x] == all[y]) {
                status[bird - 1]++; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Example Input - `1 1 2 2 3`
I want the output - `2 2 1 0 0`
But I get the output - `4 4 1 0 0`

`status[]` holds the frequency of element. `status[]` has only 5 indexes, and `all[]` has input in range of 1 to 5 only.

Here, the 1 at `x = 1` is counting frequency of itself again, but I don't want that.

Is there a logic to skip the duplicate elements without increasing the complexity of the code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Hard-code the "input" in the `main` function.

Comment: @NORAGAMI, If input was `1 2 2 3 1`, would you still want output `2 2 1 0 0`?

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica, 2x`1`, 2x`2`, 1x`3`, 0x`4`, 0x`5` (2 2 1 0 0). `1 3 10 10 3` is not a legal input ("in range of 1 to 5 only").

Comment: @ikegami I was hoping for OP to respond. Sorry I did not get the _@NORAGAMI_ edited in the first time.

Comment: The tag or lack thereof does not affect the answer.

Comment: for 1 2 2 3 1, i would want the same 2 2  1 0 0, as the 0th index stores frequency of 1 and so on for 5 integers.

Answer (score 2):

Your code assumes that the value range is `1` to `n`. In that case, you can simply increase the corresponding counter for each value:

```
// Reset all counters. This can be skipped if "status" is initialized to all zeroes {0}
// The code below assumes "status" is an array. Otherwise, the count must
// be the length (in case of the OP, this is 5).
for(int x=0; x < sizeof(status)/sizeof(status[0]); x++) {
    status[x] = 0;
}

// Count each occurrence. If elements of "all" may be out of range, a range check
// must be added.
for(int x=0; x<n; x++) {
    status[all[x]-1]++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need

```c
for ( size_t i = 5; i--; )
   status[ i ] = 0;

for ( size_t i = n; i--; )
   ++status[ all[ i ] - 1 ];
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to use only one for loop as for example

```
for ( int x = 0; x < n; x++ ) {
    bird = all[x];
    status[bird-1]++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot!

Comment: @NORAGAMI No at all. You are welcome.:)